# load local json file issues

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having as issue loading a localhosted json file. The url path is correct. I have no idea why it isnt working. IDeas would be lovely

```
 $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           crossDomain: true,
           dataType: 'json',
           url: '../json/test.json',
           success: function(json) {
               //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
               for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
                   var title = json.results[i].event;
                   var href = json.results[i].event;
                   var button =
                       "<button class='redirect-button' color='green' data-url='" +
                       href + "'>Compare</button>";
                   $("#apple").append("<tbody><tr><td>" + title +
                       "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr></tbody>"
                   );
                   $("#apple").find(".redirect-button").click(function() {
                       location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
                   });
               }
           },
           error: function(error) {
               console.log(error);
           }
       });
```

Comment: Is it on chrome? It happens to have problems with that. Try loading the same stuff in apache and it'll work with no problem. Otherwise you may change the settings of chrome to accept this, you have to google that, sorry it was long time ago I had this problem.

Comment: is there no work around for people who use chrome? like client wise?

Comment: Is there an  error-message in the browser console? I used your code and it worked for me (in chrome).

Comment: Sorry no, it is a security issue, they won't change this. The only thing you can do is use absolute address or use it inside a server.

Comment: no error code, just didnt appear in the table

Comment: i used the absolute address on my server which didnt work. how would i use it inside the server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think u're using the wrong parametr on the $.parseJSON, cause u defined the json as the name of the return variable on the succes: function(json) and is using the not declared data as the variable to the parsing, try to replace it to $.parseJSON(json) instead, or change the sucess: function(json) to sucess: function(data)

Comment: The only place `parseJSON` was used, it is commented out.

Comment: think it was commented after cause he tried to do it and it didn't worked, using parseJSON can inform if the error is a 'malfomed JSON', also he can use the strig returned to post it to us if there's a response to the server

Comment: If it was malformed JSON then the `error` function would be called when jQuery failed to parse the JSON before running the `success` function.

Comment: Is there a way to get the non-parsed JSON cause it throws an error? Like the string sent by the server?

Comment: Yes, it will be available through the arguments to the `error` function, but the OP said that function wasn't being called.

Comment: Hmm, ty, i think this can help me on another problem, ty